# Pagination in laravel with conditions

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I having problem with pagination, so far I looked at the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/pagination) but I can not find in there. I also looked at other post on stack overflow but they don't have the conditions I have in this case. So how can I paginate the `if` statement because I get the error

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator::$threads

because when you paginate you need to get it straight out of the model like this `model::paginate()` so how can you do it in this case?

the controller

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    if($request->has('tags')){
        $tag = Tag::find($request->tags)->paginate(10);
        $threads = $tag->threads;
    } else {
        $threads = Thread::paginate(10);
    }
    return view('thread.index', compact('threads'));
}
```

so how can you properly paginate `$tag = Tag::find($request->tags)->paginate(10);` this?

the blade that generates a link where the controller get the `tag` from if that link is clicked

```
<div class="col-md-3">
<h4>Tags</h4>
<ul class="list-group">
    <a href="{{route('thread.index')}}" class="list-group-item">
        <span class="badge">14</span>
        All Threads
    </a>
    @foreach($tags as $tag)
    <a href="{{route('thread.index',['tags' => $tag->id])}}" class="list-group-item">
        <span class="badge">14</span>
        {{$tag->name}}
    </a>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

Update

`var_dump($request->tags);` in the controller drops `string(1) "2"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `whereHas()` method to add relational conditions ([docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)).

```
if ($request->has('tags')){
    $threads = Thread::whereHas('tags', function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->whereIn('tags.id', $request->tags);
        })->paginate(10);
} else {
    $threads = Thread::paginate(10);
}
```

In this example you need to change the third line with the `whereIn` method to your correct needs.

Comment: Its giving an error back `Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::cleanBindings() must be of the type array, string given` (dont fully understand `wherein`) but I think `id` of `tags.id` in this case should be the database table name, but even if I do that its still returning the error. I also looked at this [wherein docs laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-wherein)

Comment: Does is work when you change `whereIn` to `where`. If that doesn't work: what does the `$request->tags` data look like? Could you provide a data dump.

Comment: Its working but when going to second page on the pagination it is resetting it.

Comment: You need to append the data to the pagination links. On [this page](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/pagination#displaying-pagination-results) search for `Appending To Pagination Links `. You need to do something like: `{{ $threads->appends(['tags' => $tags])->links() }}`. But then make sure to send the $tags variable to the view with the correct content from the Controller.